# Nesting doesn't work as intended

Tags: css, sass

I wanted to nest `h1` inside of `title` class, but for some reason it just doesn't want to happen.

```
.title {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  h1 {
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 500%;
  }
}
```

When inspecting elements, `h1` doesn't have any of properties above.
When I use code below instead, everything works just fine.

```
.title h1 {
  color: #717171;
  font-size: 500%;
}
```

What could be the reason for that?
I am using C9 cloud IDE with HTML template, which to my knowledge have `SCSS` pre-processor.

Comment: its working fine https://jsfiddle.net/6wL03u2d/

Answer (score 0):

If it's `sass` , then your syntax is wrong, sass and scss have different syntax.

your style in sass should be like :

```
.title 
  display: flex
  overflow: hidden
  align-items: center
  h1 
    color: #717171
    font-size: 500%
```

and in scss is like you already have :

```
.title {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  h1 {
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 500%;
  }
}
```

you can always check your sass for syntax error at [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) , this site can check sass and scss and also u can choose which version of them you want to test.

Comment: Hey, sorry that my tags have mislead you. Scss tag is almost nonexistant while Sass have much more content, that's why I tagged it that way. I'll edit post to point that it's SCSS.